# Python sending email event though there is no exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a automated python(3.x) code that executes on windows task scheduler and I have modified the code to send an email to notify me when the scripts doesn't execute or has an exception/error when executing the script.
I am facing a problem with the code, I am receiving an email even though there is no exception or error when the code is executed. The code is designed to send an email only when there is an exception or an erro when executing the scripts.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import logging
import logging.handlers

mail_content = '''Hi,

This is a sample Email.

Thank You
'''

#The mail addresses and password
sender_address = <sender_address>
sender_pass = <password>
receiver_address = <'receiver_address1', 'receiver_address2']
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['Subject'] = 'PROD ShipTime Script'   #The subject line
message['To'] = ", ".join(receiver_address)
#The body and the attachments for the mail
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))

def run_script():
    url = "url_1"
    
    payload = {}
    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'authorization'
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload).json()

    resp = json.dumps(response, indent=2)
    response1 = json.loads(resp)


    for i in range(len(response1['Response'])):
        ---do some action ----
        --- do some Action ---
        try:
            ---Do an action---
        except KeyExistsError:
            --- If there is an exception then do another Action ---
    return


def send_email(e):
    #Create SMTP session for sending the mail
    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #use gmail with port
    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls() #enable security
    session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password
    text = message.as_string()
    session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
    session.quit()


def main():
    try:
        run_script()
    except Exception as e:
        send_email(e)
        print(e)
        print("Email Sent Successfully")
```

Comment: well, on of the problem with broad exceptions like this is that it makes debugging hard. Can you log or print or email the exception traceback?

Comment: I just checked script and there is no error in the script, I tried to print the execption but there is no execption. The issue i am facing is though I there is no execption produced I am still receiving the email. I doubt about the structure in the scrpit. Sorry I am new to pyton

Comment: You could change `except Exception:` to `except Exception as e:` then pass `e` to `send_email` so it includes the exception description in the email. That's probably what you want even if there really is an error.

Comment: wow I just did that and I dint see any error, I updated my code above